# math.h linker error using sin() in C

Tags: c, linker, type-conversion, math.h

I have two segments of code, both identical except for one line. One program fails to compile, and the other one is successful. I do link the math libraries when I execute cc to compile the code.

I'm using the `double sin(double)` function.  It's apparently defined in math.h, although I looked in /usr/include/math.h and found no reference to the `sin()` function.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Trig-Functions

The `sin()` function does work in one code segment I give but not in the other.

```
//Successful program - demo1.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
    double input, sine_A; 
    input = 6.2830;
    sine_A = sin(6.2830);
    printf("sine=%f\n",sine_A);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the failed program:

```
//Failed program - demo2.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
    double input, sine_A;
    input = 6.2830;
    sine_A = sin(input);
    printf("sine=%f\n",sine_A);
    return 0;
}

$ cc -lm demo2.c

/tmp/ccnpIWZd.o: In function `main':
demo2.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `sin'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This has been leaving me feeling a bit stupid, or at least, feeling I missed something over the years.

Comment: I believe you are right.  I wish I had read this last week.  This was what I would have liked to have found.  Thank's for sending this my way!

Comment: Very similar to [log(10.0) can compile but log(0.0) cannot?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24294578/1708801)

Comment: @KeithThompson please see [Is this conflict of interest an abuse of closing privileges?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277126/1708801) I pretty much avoid closing question as duplicates of questions I have an answer on since I agree with George this seems like a conflict of interest. As I commented to him it seems like in these cases the dup hammer should change to a regular non-binding vote. In cases were someone else does not find a better duplicate the advice seems to be flag it or post on meta.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: I don't agree that it's a conflict of interest, though I suppose I can see how it might appear that way. In my opinion, this question is clearly a duplicate of the other one (and probably of a number of others). I think there was a comment referring to the other question (which apparently was later deleted). I didn't even remember that I had posted an answer, though I was aware of it before I cast my vote. It had also slipped my mind that I can close a C question as a duplicate with a single vote. Do you disagree that this is a duplicate of that question?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Also, I wouldn't mind having an option either to close a question by myself *or* to cast an ordinary close vote, but that mechanism doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

You are not linking with the math library. If you are using `gcc` you need to pass `-lm` at the end.

So why is the first example working ? I can speculate that's happening because you are calling `sin` directly on a double literal and `gcc` can do its own magic without requiring libm - it can simply compute it directly and replace the call entirely with the result.

Comment: I tried `gcc -lm a.c` without any problem.

Comment: It is interesting, I just noticed that if I exclude the "-lm"  as a parameter of cc, the outcome is exactly the same.  The failed one still fails and the successful one still compiles.

Comment: @TimothyLegg are you putting `-lm` **at the end** ?

Comment: I moved it to the end, and both compile properly.  Thanks for solving this.  I swear that I used to pass "-lm" before INFILE in the past; could this have changed?  This usage works, but contradicts the man page for cc.

Comment: @TimothyLegg There's a [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/fp/libm.html).

Answer (score 1):

`-lm` needs to be at the end of the command, most likely in the first case with the literal the compiler is optimizing out the call to `sin` and therefore does not need to link against the library. This is called [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) and for example we can see in the `gcc` docs on [Other Built-in Functions Provided by GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins) says(*emphasis mine*):

> GCC includes built-in versions of many of the functions in the
>   standard C library. The versions prefixed with __builtin_ are always
>   treated as having the same meaning as the C library function even if
>   you specify the -fno-builtin option. (see C Dialect Options) Many of
>   these functions are only optimized in certain cases; **if they are not
>   optimized in a particular case, a call to the library function is
>   emitted.**

Here is a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b902561a1d13c35c) which we can see from the assembly in the literal case `gcc` optimizes out the call to `sin` and this [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b51f2f5c8fa0fe9) shows the non-literal case and we see in the assembly:

```
call    sin
```

Comment: Just curious, how is the first one optimized out? I see it uses a constant and the second uses a variable, but how did you make that leap?

Comment: @cnicutar says - `calling sin directly on a double literal and gcc can do its own magic without requiring libm`, I think that might be the answer, you just got there empirically :)

Comment: @KevinDTimm I think we are saying the same thing