# Issues with log() call

Tags: c

Why won't this program run?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%f\n", log(36.0));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you trying and what goes wrong when you try?

Comment: You had better to `#include <math.h>`. The prototype of log is `double log(double arg);` and, as you have not included it, the compiler is assuming it returns an `int` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to include

```
#include<math.h>
```

This is because math.h is a header file in the standard library of C programming language designed for basic mathematical operations.

Comment: And link the math library with `-lm` as a compiler option.

Comment: @squiguy actually in this case both `gcc` and `clang` can [use  builtin functions if the argument is a constant expression in many cases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24294632/1708801) but in the general case you need to use `-lm`.