# Need to use -lm in Clang with pow(), but not sqrt()

Tags: c, clang

On FreeBSD `10.1` and using Clang version `3.4.1`

Now I have seen other threads asking **how to compile with using pow()**, but I haven't seen a thread with this question. Take for example:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  float result;
  result = pow(2,3);
  printf("%d", result);
  return 0;
}
```

Now using `pow()`, I need to issue clang the argument -lm.

> cc -lm -o name name.c

However, replacing `pow(2,3)` with `sqrt(5);`, I can compile with `cc -o name name.c`. If they both use `math.h`, then why does `pow()` need to be linked to the library?
Side not: Installed gcc to test, and I don't need to use -lm at all.

Comment: See [log(10.0) can compile but log(0.0) cannot?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24294578/1708801) basically it is using a builtin and so in those cases it does not need to link against the math library.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I think that's a different issue. The compiler is evaluating `log(10.0)` rather than writing code to evaluate at runtime.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I don't agree.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well the best way to test is to use -fno-builtin if that changes the need for -lm then it is indeed the case.

Comment: Indeed using `-fno-builtin` forces `-lm` to be required [see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b04f743ad98ac1e) so this is indeed the same issue as I linked above. In order to make the above program work we would have to add `-lm`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are targeting a processor whose floating point hardware implements `sqrt` directly, as do all IEEE-754 compliant units. As such, the compiler can generate code for `sqrt` directly and does not need to link to a library function.

On the other hand, floating point hardware does not typically offer implementations of `pow` and so it does need to be implemented in a library.