# Unusual behavior of pow() in C during compilation

Tags: c, gcc, pow, math.h

Program file name - armstrong3.c.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
int i, sum, num, rem,x;
x=pow(2,5);
printf("%d\n", x);
printf("List of 3 digit armstrong numbers \n");
for (i=100; i<=999; i++) {
    num=i;
    sum=0;
    while (num>0) {
        rem=num%10;
        sum=sum+pow(rem,3);
        num/=10;
    }
    if (i==sum) 
        printf("%d\n", i);  
    }
return 0;
}
```

This simple program finds 3 digit armstrong numbers. To calculate the cube I am using `pow()` of `math.h`. It didn't work initially and gave the famous error during compilation:

> armstrong3.c:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `pow' collect2:
>
> error: ld returned 1 exit status.

Then I compiled it with `gcc armstrong.c -lm`, and it worked fine.

Then I used another `pow()` function in the second line of the `main()` function and commented out the earlier `pow()` function which I was using to calculate the cube. Strangely, the program compiled fine with `gcc armstrong3.c`.

The program posted by me gets compiles fine using `gcc armstrong.c -lm`.

The following scenario is my current issue:

With the second `pow()` commented out it `gcc armstrong.c` compiles with no warnings and errors. No `-lm` flag required.

If I uncomment the second `pow()` function in the program, it does not compile and gives the above mentioned error. And with `-lm` it works fine.

Why is there this unusual behavior with the same function in two places inside the same program?

Compiler: gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04).

Comment: See [log(10.0) can compile but log(0.0) cannot?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24294578/1708801) basically gcc can optimize away calls to certain builtins when using constant expression arguments. Try using `-fno-builtin`

Answer (score 4):

> Then I used another pow() function in the second line of the main() function and commented out the earlier pow() function which I was using to calculate the cube. Strangely, the program compiled fine with gcc armstrong3.c.

`pow` is an intrinsic function. When you specify all its arguments as compile time constants, as in `pow(2, 5)`, the compiler replaces the call with its value.

That only happens for integer arguments. Because when you pass floating point arguments the result of `pow` depends on the current [floating point rounding mode](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/feround), which is not known at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is caused by inlining the `pow` function result in case of constant expressions in its call.

Comment: Is there a reference link documenting this behavior of `gcc`?

Comment: @rootkea: I don't know about such reference, but it should be easy to confirm that by inspecting the generated code.

Comment: @rootkea You don't need a special documentation for this. The compiler knows how this function works (because it's a standard C function) and it has every right to replace the call with a better equivalent, a constant in this case.